# Crystal Reports ONLY print date code and serial numbers IF NOT blank

Tags: crystal-reports

Hello StackOverflow community and experts.

I am new with `Crystal Reports` and I am trying to figure out how to ONLY `print date` code and `serial numbers` IF NOT blank. I have searched online for code examples and see what others have asked and what answers were returned.

Although, I have not found what I am looking for, I have found many suggestions for using the surpress in the solution.

Also, I have noticed a lot of online code examples that begin with a question mark. What does the question mark indicate?

Comment: One that begins with `?` is the parameter in crystal report..which field are you checking for `If not` blank condition?

Comment: @Siva I am trying to ONLY print date code and serial numbers IF NOT blank. The Serial Number is ShortChar01 and Date is ShortChar03. It is tied in with Epicor and using the rmadtl table = rmadtl.ShortChar01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding below is the code:

Serial Number:

```
if(ISNULL(rmadtl.ShortChar01))
then 
//your code
else 
rmadtl.ShortChar01
```

Date:

```
if(ISNULL(rmadtl.ShortChar03))
then 
//your code
else 
rmadtl.ShortChar03
```

In both the cases checking the null condition and if it is write required code you need else pring the serial number and date

Let me know if this not your requirement.

Comment: thank you. I will try it out and let you know! Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: this is what Crystal needed:                                                                                                           IF ({rmadtl.ShortChar01}) = ""
OR
(ISNULL ({rmadtl.Shortchar01})) 
THEN 
TRUE

Comment: so there seems to be another problem now.
I have used the following code: 
[code]IF ({rmadtl.ShortChar01}) = ""
OR
(ISNULL ({rmadtl.Shortchar01})) 
THEN 
TRUE[/code]
for the Serial Number which is from the rmadtl table and is ShortChar01 field. This works and hides any serial numbers that are empty strings.
BUT...
[code]IF ({rmadtl.ShortChar03}) = ""
OR
(ISNULL ({rmadtl.Shortchar03})) 
THEN 
TRUE[/code]
does NOT hide the Dates. It still shows "Date:" and also "0"
I don't know why this is happening for the date field but not the serial number field. Does anybody else know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax that Crystal Reports needed to work properly was:

IF ({rmadtl.ShortChar01}) = ""
OR
(ISNULL ({rmadtl.Shortchar01})) 
THEN 
TRUE